# sbt: How to run integration test

Tags: scala, sbt, integration-testing

According to the [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests):

> The standard testing tasks are available, but must be prefixed with
>   it:. For example,
>
> `> IntegrationTest / testOnly org.example.AnIntegrationTest`

As described, I added this to my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
```

I want to run only integration tests.

So I tried different ways - but none worked:

```
[IJ][play-binding-form-server] $ it:test
[error] No such setting/task
[error] it:test
...
[IJ][play-binding-form-server] $ IntegrationTest / testOnly org.example.AnIntegrationTest
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Expected '/'
[error] IntegrationTest / testOnly org.example.AnIntegrationTest
```

How is it done correctly?

Comment: Current documentation: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enable `settings(Defaults.itSettings)` like here

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings)
```

After this you should be able to run both within sbt

```
sbt> it:testOnly test.Spec
sbt> IntegrationTest / testOnly test.Spec
```

Or outside of `sbt` as

```
sbt "it:testOnly test.Spec"
sbt "IntegrationTest / testOnly test.Spec"
```

Comment: thanks! `.settings(Defaults.itSettings)` was the missing part!