# SBT + IntellIj Not Recognising My Integration Test Directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to set up integration test folder for my project. So in I added the following to my SBT build definition:

```scala
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath :=
      (IntegrationTest / dependencyClasspath).value ++ (Test / exportedProducts).value,
    Keys.fork in IntegrationTest := false,
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in IntegrationTest := (baseDirectory in IntegrationTest)(base => Seq(base / "it")).value,
    resourceDirectory in IntegrationTest := baseDirectory.value / "it/resources",
    parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false
  )
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
src
  |-it
     |-scala
```

But if I start an sbt session and do `it:test` it does not pick up any of the tests. Also Intellij is not marking the `it` directory green as well which is the colour of test folders. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that this line is incorrect:

```scala
unmanagedSourceDirectories in IntegrationTest := (baseDirectory in IntegrationTest)(base => Seq(base / "it")).value
```

In majority of the cases, if you are not doing any exotic custom integration setup, the default settings that come with sbt are fine. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251564/3248346) post.